# How to detect winjs list view scroll start?

Tags: javascript, listview, win-universal-app, scrollbar, winjs

I am working with a list view in winjs, **WinJS.UI.ListView**.

```
<div class="list-of-lists-listview" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
```

will this fire some event on scroll start.
I have another `<div>` which I need to make visible when we start scrolling the list view.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="list-of-lists-listview" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
```

Inside JS, get the list view like

```
  var currentListView = document.querySelector(".list-of-lists-listview");
```

Do not add the scroll event handler directly to the control instead get the view port for the list view using below code,

```
 var currentViewPort = currentListView.querySelector(".win-viewport");
```

Now add listener to this view port

```
currentViewPort.addEventListener("scroll", this._onScroll, true);
```

write handler named _onScroll where we can write our code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the scroll event of ListView Control, you can leverage the Html API:

HTML:

```
<div id="myListView" 
     class="list-of-lists-listview" 
     style="height:500px;overflow:scroll" 
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" >
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("myListView").onscroll = function (evt)
{
    ...
}
```

Notes: You need to set the height of `ListView` explicitly and `overflow:scroll` to show the scrollbar.

Comment: this doesn't worked. But on running the app this control will render a view port for the list view. if we added the scroll event to that view port it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the support:)